# Two Select Statements in one MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the following result:

```
{'myExamPackages': [ { id: 1, examName: 'AWS Developer Associate Exam 
Package', examDescription: 'Looking', price: 15, 
 examimage: "aws.png", category: "AWS", myExam: [63, 64] }]}
```

I have to following two queries which i am trying to bring together.

This statement returns the ExamPackageID of the exams you have bought so 1,2

```
SELECT BoughtPackage.ExamPackageexamID as 'id', 
ExamPackage.examName, 
ExamPackage.examDescription, 
ExamPackage.price, 
ExamPackage.examimage, 
ExamPackage.category,
ExamPackage.topics,
ExamPackage.numberOfTests 
FROM CloudExams.`Order` 
JOIN BoughtPackage 
ON CloudExams.`Order`.orderID = CloudExams.BoughtPackage.orderID  
JOIN ExamPackage 
ON BoughtPackage.ExamPackageexamID = ExamPackage.examID 
WHERE userID = ?
```

This statement returns the following the myExam array:

```
SELECT myTest.myTestID 
FROM myTest 
JOIN Test 
ON myTest.testID = Test.testID 
JOIN ExamPackage 
ON Test.examID = ExamPackage.examID
WHERE ExamPackage.examID = ? 
AND myTest.userId = ?
```

Here is my ERD
[image]

Im pretty sure there is a way to do it but cannot see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please reformat your sql queries using multiple lines and indentation so that we can read them. Thanks.

Comment: You want JSON output?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes please